# Migrating ASP.NET 2005 to 2010 issue with crystal report reference.[ transferred my site from Wserver 2003 to wserver 2013 ]

Tags: crystal-reports

Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Is the new version of Crystal installed on the webserver? If not, is the assembly present in the /bin directory?

Comment: New version of Crystal is not installed yet on the webserver...

Comment: @laylarenee Now crystal report is installed on server.Now some report are working correct but error for some reports..[ERROR in log is: :SetLogOnInfo Err:Message : Logon failed.
Details: Error Code: 0x
Source: ADODB.Connection
Description: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.
Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\OrderReport {424C76E2-A19F-484D-B720-C281DB906F88}.rpt:Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters. Inner Exception :  Stack Trace : at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DatabaseControllerClass.SetTableLocation(ISCRTable CurTable, ISCRTable NewTable)

Answer (score 2):

Crystal can be, touchy to deploy and run if it's not your server (e.g. you don't have access to deploy there and possibly make tweaks).  If it's your server, not a problem.  Go get the Crystal merge modules from sap.com and install them on your server, then you will just need to reference them in your web.config.  You may run into other issues with permissions (Crystal in some circumstances uses the C:\Windows\Temp directory to export files which hosted servers will at lot of times prevent you from using, I assume this is a throw back to the fact their codebase dates back to the Windows 3.x era).

I'm going to provide the links to the downloads page at SAP:

- http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?original_fqdn=wiki.sdn.sap.com&pageId=56787567

You're using version 10.2 (which is pretty old, Crystal is pretty good about backwards compatibility so if you're in a pinch you can use newer Crystal DLL's and they should export your reports fine).